# WooCommerce: Guest Checkout Not Working

Tags: woocommerce

I have been trying to figure out how to make my guest checkout-enabled website work but with no success so far. I have the following WooCommerce settings activated:

- Enable guest checkout
- Enable registration on "Checkout" page

Normally, users should be able to checkout without creating an account, but can, however, opt to create an account if they want to. But if I place a test order as guest and check the "Create account?" box + fill out username and password fields, none of the information provided for billing and shipping shows up on the Thank You page or in the WP dashboard. It's as if the "Create account?" box + username and password would be ignored.

I suspect it has something to do with me having changed the default position of the account registration fields. I have added them to the form-login.php file so it shows up in the same section as the login form. They were originally included in the form-billing.php field. Below please find these files:

form-billing.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Checkout billing information form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-billing.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see     https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author  WooThemes
 * @package WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version 2.1.2
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

/** @global WC_Checkout $checkout */

?>
<div id="woocommerce-billing-fields" class="woocommerce-billing-fields">
<h3 class="billing-fields-title">Billing Address</h3>
    <?php
do_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_billing_form', $checkout);
?>

    <?php
foreach ($checkout->checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field):
?>

        <?php
    woocommerce_form_field($key, $field, $checkout->get_value($key));
?>

    <?php
endforeach;
?>



    <?php
do_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', $checkout);
?>




</div>
```

form-login.php:

```
<?php wc_print_notices(); ?>
<?php echo '<div class="panel-group" id="checkout-accordion">'; ?>
<?php
/**
 * Checkout login form
 *
 * This template can be overridden by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/checkout/form-login.php.
 *
 * HOWEVER, on occasion WooCommerce will need to update template files and you
 * (the theme developer) will need to copy the new files to your theme to
 * maintain compatibility. We try to do this as little as possible, but it does
 * happen. When this occurs the version of the template file will be bumped and
 * the readme will list any important changes.
 *
 * @see         https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/
 * @author         WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

if (is_user_logged_in() || 'no' === get_option('woocommerce_enable_checkout_login_reminder')) {
    return;
}

echo '<div class="panel panel-default checkout-panel" id="panel-login">
    <div class="panel-heading checkout-heading" id="panel-login-heading" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-login">
      <h4 class="panel-title checkout-acc-title"> <a class="accordion-checkout">Login/Register <i id="checkout-accordion-login" class="checkout-accordion-icon">&#xe04b;</i></a> </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse-login" class="panel-collapse details collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body checkout-inside"><div class="checkout-left-login"><h3 class="login-option">Login</h3>';
$info_message = apply_filters('woocommerce_checkout_login_message', '<div class="already-registered">' . __('Already registered?', 'woocommerce') . '</div>');
wc_print_notice($info_message, 'notice');

?>



<?php

woocommerce_login_form(
    array(
        'redirect' => wc_get_page_permalink( 'checkout' ),
        'hidden'   => true,
    )
);
echo '</div>';

?>


<?php
if (!is_user_logged_in() && $checkout->enable_signup):
?>

        <?php
    if ($checkout->enable_guest_checkout):
?>

            <p class="form-row form-row-wide create-account">
                <input class="input-checkbox" id="createaccount" <?php
        checked((true === $checkout->get_value('createaccount') || (true === apply_filters('woocommerce_create_account_default_checked', false))), true);
?> type="checkbox" name="createaccount" value="1" /> <label for="createaccount" class="checkbox"><?php
        _e('Create an account?', 'woocommerce');
?></label>
            </p>

        <?php
    endif;
?>

        <?php
    do_action('woocommerce_before_checkout_registration_form', $checkout);
?>

        <?php
    if (!empty($checkout->checkout_fields['account'])):
?>

<div class="checkout-right-register">
<h3 class="login-option">Create an Account</h3>
            <div class="create-account">




                <?php
        foreach ($checkout->checkout_fields['account'] as $key => $field):
?>

                    <?php
            woocommerce_form_field($key, $field, $checkout->get_value($key));
?>

                <?php
        endforeach;
?>

                <div class="clear"></div>

            </div>



<?php
    endif;
?>

        <?php
    do_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_registration_form', $checkout);
?>

    <?php
endif;
?>




<button id="toggle-login" type="button" class="register-btn-checkout" data-toggle="collapse" onclick="setCookie('panel-billing')" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-billing">Continue</button>


</div><div class="or-select-guest">OR</div><button id="toggle-login2" type="button" class="guest-btn-checkout" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#checkout-accordion" href="#collapse-billing" onclick="setCookie('panel-billing')">Checkout as Guest</button> 

<?php echo'</div></div></div>';

?>
```

As a side note: the whole checkout form will be an accordion, with sections for delivery + billing, delivery options, and payment.

Am I missing anything? I suspect the issue might be related to the Woocommerce actions, but I can't tell for sure.

Answer (score 5):

Are you using Woocommerce Subscriptions by any chance? I ask because I just had a similar issue and finally realized that guest checkout was actually working for any product except subscription products. I happened to be testing the checkout page with a subscription product in my cart... Since purchasing a subscription product assigns a user role, having one in the cart will require an account at checkout.

This may not help your specific situation, but maybe it will help someone else looking for answers.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me! I had subscriptions and could not figure out why is it asking for registration if I enabled guest checkout.